# Using AWS Alexa in Java to start a Desktop app

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am thinking about making an Alexa skill that would allow people to start a game or desktop app on their PC. I am thinking about having the PC running a Java server and using a JSON config to name keys that match to the command to start the game such as this:

```
{
  "serverPort": 9023,
  "apps": {
    "minecraft": { // Name Alexa uses to start game
      "command": "minecraft.exe", // Command the Desktop will execute
    },
    "fortnite": {
      "command": "fortnite.exe"
    }
  }
}
```

The Alexa skill will connect to the server, authenticate both server (PC) and client (Alexa) using a token created when they were first linked and then send a packet telling the server what game to start. The server will either respond with a success packet or a failure packet and then the connection closes.

I've never used AWS and even less know of AWS Lambda so that is why I am asking about this setup. Would I need to self-host this or is it possible with the free tier of AWS Lambda? And also, what would be the best way to link both Alexa and PC, and possibly later on allow multiple PCs to be linked?

P.S I am going to use Netty for the networking in both client and server

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with Lambda it a bit different than a server. Whenever you ask lambda for something it turns on and delivers for you and then turns off. This means you don't have to have something running for 24 hours and can just have lambda deal with requests as they come. With a server its basically the same thing except its running for 24 hours.

I'm not sure if lambda would work or how many requests lambda can handle, but you could look into it.

I hope i helped :)